# Deploying VueJS app - Back end (ExpressJS) Not Responding

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

This is my first time deploying a VueJS app.  It is full stack, back end is Express/MySQL.  All running fine in developer mode.  My dev platform is Windows 10, VS Code.

I am currently trying to preview the app on my dev PC using local webserver.

To that end, I built Vue app to server/public.  The static site then runs fine, but I can't seem to get the Express back end to respond, either from the app or from browser accessing the api directly.  I followed a model from Brad Traversy tutorial, here is what vue.config.js looks like:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, './server/public'),
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000'
      }
    }
  },
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],

  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      locale: 'en',
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
      localeDir: 'locales',
      enableInSFC: false,
    },
  },
};
```

Here is the index.js for Express/back end.  I commented out the NODE_ENV test because I haven't yet figured out how to set it properly.  This should just hardwire the code to run in production mode.  __dirname points to the server directory, which contains the Express code and other server stuff.

```
// Create express app
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
//Create Express App
const app = express();
// Add Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
// 
const water = require('./routes/api/water');
const waterlog = require('./routes/api/waterlog');
// Direct /api
app.use('/api/water', water);
app.use('/api/waterlog', waterlog);
// Handle production
// if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Static folder
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
  // Handle SPA
  app.get(/.*/, (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
// }

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`CORS-EnabledServer started on port ${port}`));
```

I use (from npm serve) this to start the Vue app:

```
 serve -s server/public
```

What am I missing?  Feels very close but no cigar yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`serve`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) is just a simple, static HTTP server. It won't run your backend.

Your production build puts your front-end assets into your Express app's statically served directory so all you should need to do after building the front-end is start your server

```sh
# Build your front-end
npm run build

# Start your Express server, assuming this is configured in package.json
NODE_ENV=production npm start
```

Now open http://localhost:5000/ in your browser

See also https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#set-node_env-to-production

Comment: Thanks for your clearly presented answer. Simple as it is, it revealed a couple of things that I hadn't put together yet.  Breakthrough!